# How to get xpath from "Page Should Contain" in a web page using RobotFramework and Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I'm writing test cases for a webpage that has a table as the main focus of the page. I'm checking that the page contains a new entry via the Page Should Contain fucntion, I then want to find the xpath for this element. I am doing this because each entry is added to the end of the table so I cannot set a static xpath for it because I don't know how many entries will be added between each run of this particular test.

Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="fw-table">
<thead>
   <tr class="affix-header">
      <th class="columnwidth-description">Email</th>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Signed up</th>
      <th>Number of invalid attempts</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>devtest</td>
      <td><a href="/#!/accounts/5">Account</a></td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>test@testing.com</td>
      <td><a href="/#!/accounts/40">Account</a></td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
```

search for: xpath=//body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML code

Comment: <table class="fw-table"><thead>
<tr class="affix-header">
    <th class="columnwidth-description">Email</th>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Signed up</th>
    <th>Number of invalid attempts</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>devtest</td>
        <td><a href="/#!/accounts/5">Account</a></td>
        <td>true</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mhills__@bottomline.com</td>
        <td><a href="/#!/accounts/40">Account</a></td>
        <td>true</td>
        <td>1</td>
</tr>

Comment: Sorry, the company firewall prevents jscript frombloadibgn.. I cant comment on my computer, I'm using my phone.

Comment: How dou define "the xpath"? The one that has every ancestor, or one that uses an id, or will any xpath do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to verify that last table row contains certain text you can use the `Page Should Contain Element` keyword and provide an xpath locator which will find the last table row containing your text:

```
Page Should Contain Element    xpath=//table[@class="fw-table"]//tr[last()]//td[contains(text(),'bottomline')]
```

Comment: finspin is right about using last() in the predicate. A slight alternative I would consider is: Element Text Should Be    xpath=//table[@class="fw-table"]/tbody/tr[last()]//td[1]    mhills__@bottomline.com